# Python - How do i change the child of a child of an object?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to make a python script that will recursively rename the children in a hierarchy with a name derived after their parent, from a selected object.

Now I've gotten as far as I can select an object, run the script - and it will rename all the children accordingly.

The problem is that, if those children also has children of their own - I also want to rename those as well. But I cant find a way to rename the child of a child of an object.

I'm pretty new to python, but any solution or advice for what I should be looking at is much appreciated.

So heres what little I got so far:

```
    def execute(self, context):
    
    
    for child in bpy.context.object.children:
        
         
        #Rename child to "[ParentName]_[Type]"
        child.name = bpy.context.object.name + ("_") + child.type 

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Share the script you got so far with this post please.

Comment: oh sorry, I've added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Extending a list of Children

You can make a list of children and extend the list with the children of each child. After renaming a children, it is removed from the list.

```
import bpy

def execute(context):
    ob = context.object
    
    if ob == None:
        return
    
    children = list(ob.children)
    index = 0
    while len(children):
        child = children.pop()
        child.name = ob.name + str(index).zfill(3)
        children.extend(child.children)
        index += 1
        
execute(bpy.context)
```

## Recursively walking the Children

You can also create a function, which renames the children of an object (parameter) and calls itself for each of the children.

```
import bpy

def renameChildren(ob):
    for child in ob.children:
        child.name = ob.name + "_" + child.type
        renameChildren(child)

def execute(context):
    ob = context.object
    
    if ob == None:
        return
    
    renameChildren(ob)
        
execute(bpy.context)
```

Comment: that's great! thank you very much!